# ¿Cuál sería el equivalente de has() de jquery en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Encontré un código en `codepen` para realizar un auto complete, y tiene código `jquery` estoy intentando traducirlo a `javascript` puro pero tengo una duda con la función *`has()`* de `jquery`.

¿Cuál sería su equivalencia en javascript?

```
function removeListBlur() {
  if (filterSelect.has("li").length) {
    filterSelect.addClass("no-value").children("li").remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: Para recibir una respuesta lo mas acertada posible sería necesario saber a que es igual `filterSelect`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo equivalente de `has()` de jquery en javascript seria :

```
  FiltetSelect.querySelector("li").length
```

Comment: Realizar respuestas en base a [answer]

Answer (score 2):

No existe un equivalente directo de `.has()` en JavaScript, puedes imitar su comportamiento mediante código propio.

> La documentación de JQuery muestra como lo realiza [aquí](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/56136897f241db22560b58c3518578ca1453d5c7/src/traversing.js#L27)

Algo así tal vez podría funcionarte:

```
var lis = document.getElementById("idOfFilterSelect").getElementsByTagName("li");

if(lis.lenght){
 document.getElementById("idOfFilterSelect").addClass("no-value");
 while (lis.hasChildNodes()) {   
     list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
 }
}
```

> `lis` es una NodeList, no una matriz, sí tiene .length y puede iterar sobre ella como una matriz.